# This C function should always return false, but it doesn’t

Tags: c, gcc

I stumbled over an interesting question in a forum a long time ago and I want to know the answer.

Consider the following C function:

### f1.c

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool f1()
{
    int var1 = 1000;
    int var2 = 2000;
    int var3 = var1 + var2;
    return (var3 == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

This should always return `false` since `var3 == 3000`. The `main` function looks like this:

### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    printf( f1() == true ? "true\n" : "false\n");
    if( f1() )
    {
        printf("executed\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since `f1()` should always return `false`, one would expect the program to print only one *false* to the screen. But after compiling and running it, *executed* is also displayed:

```
$ gcc main.c f1.c -o test
$ ./test
false
executed
```

Why is that? Does this code have some sort of undefined behavior?

Note: I compiled it with `gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2`.

Comment: Others have mentioned you need a prototype because your functions are in separate files. But even if you copied `f1()` into the same file as `main()`, you'd get some weirdness: While it is correct in C++ to use `()` for an empty parameter list, in C that is used for a function with a not-yet-defined parameter list (it basically expects a K&R-style parameter list after the `)`). To be correct C, you should change your code to `bool f1(void)`.

Comment: The `main()` could be simplified to `int main()
{
    puts(f1() == true ? "true" : "false");
    puts(f1()         ? "true" : "false");
    return 0;
}` – this would show the discrepancy better.

Comment: @uliwitness What about K&R 1st ed. (1978) when there was no `void`?

Comment: @uliwitness There were not `true` and `false` in K&R 1st ed., so there were not such problems at all. It was just 0 and non-zero for true and false. Isn't it? I don't know if prototypes were available at that time.

Comment: K&R 1st Edn preceded prototypes (and the C standard) by more than a decade (1978 for the book vs 1989 for the standard) — indeed, C++ (C with Classes) was still in the future when K&R1 was published.  Also, prior to C99, there was no `_Bool` type and no `<stdbool.h>` header.

Comment: Uhm, is this line `printf( f1() == true ? "true\n" : "false\n");` ok? I mean is it ensured that it will be executed in the expected order?! Which rule does ensure that?

Answer (score 413, accepted):

As noted in other answers, the problem is that you use `gcc` with no compiler options set. If you do this, it defaults to what is called "gnu90", which is a non-standard implementation of the old, withdrawn C90 standard from 1990.

In the old C90 standard there was a major flaw in the C language: if you didn't declare a prototype before using a function, it would default to `int func ()` (where `( )` means "accept any parameter"). This changes the calling convention of the function `func`, but it doesn't change the actual function definition. Since the size of `bool` and `int` are different, your code invokes undefined behavior when the function is called.

This dangerous nonsense behavior was fixed in the year 1999, with the release of the C99 standard. Implicit function declarations were banned.

Unfortunately, GCC up to version 5.x.x still uses the old C standard by default. There is probably no reason why you should want to compile your code as anything but standard C. So you have to explicitly tell GCC that it should compile your code as modern C code, instead of some 25+ years old, non-standard GNU crap.

Fix the problem by always compiling your program as:

```
gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra
```

- `-std=c11` tells it to make a half-hearted attempt to compile according the (current) C standard (informally known as C11).
- `-pedantic-errors` tells it to whole-heartedly do the above, and give compiler errors when you write incorrect code which violates the C standard.
- `-Wall` means give me some extra warnings that might be good to have.
- `-Wextra` means give me some other extra warnings that might be good to have.

Comment: This answer is overall correct, but for more complicated programs `-std=gnu11` is much more likely to work as expected than `-std=c11`, due to any or all of: needing library functionality beyond C11 (POSIX, X/Open, etc) that is available in the "gnu" extended modes but suppressed in the strict conformance mode; bugs in system headers that are hidden in the extended modes, e.g. assuming availability of nonstandard typedefs; unintentional use of trigraphs (this standard misfeature is disabled in "gnu" mode).

Comment: For similar reasons, while I generally encourage use of high warnings levels I cannot support the use of warnings-are-errors modes.  `-pedantic-errors` is less troublesome than `-Werror` but both can and do cause programs to fail to compile on operating systems that are not included in the original author's testing, even when there is no actual problem.

Comment: @zwol I doubt that is a problem for anyone but Linux programmers. I bet the majority of C programmers couldn't care less about getting some messy, non-standard Linux code to compile. I have never in my life seen an accidental trigraph bug. GCC warns for using trigraphs anyway.

Comment: @Lundin On the contrary, the second problem I mentioned (bugs in the system headers that are exposed by strict conformance modes) is *ubiquitous*; I have done extensive, systematic testing, and there are *no* widely used operating systems that do not have at least one such bug (as of two years ago, anyway).  C programs that require only the functionality of C11, with no further additions, are also the exception rather than the rule in my experience.

Comment: @zwol There is all kinds of programming beyond desktop operative systems. For example all the computer firmware inside your Linux PC (harddrives, graphics cards, BIOS, sound card, DVD etc etc) is likely written in C.

Comment: @Lundin Are you seriously claiming that those programs are all written in strictly conforming C11 and that those (semi-freestanding) implementations are, as a rule, free of bugs exposed by using them in strict conformance mode?  Because I don't believe that for a nanosecond.

Comment: The best advace, IMHO is: avoid Bool and BOOL and bool and Boolean. It is bullshit, you don' *need* it. Just a plain int (or char) will do just as well, and will cause less confusion.

Comment: @zwol Probably not in strict C11, but they could be written in strict C90 or strict C99. At any rate, they will certainly not use POSIX and likely not non-standard GCC extensions.

Comment: @joop If you use standard C `bool`/`_Bool` then you can write your C code in a "C++-esque" way, where you assume that all comparisons and logical operators return a `bool` like in C++, even though they return an `int` in C, for historical reasons. This has the great advantage that you can use static analysis tools to check for type safety of all such expressions, and expose all kinds of bugs at compile-time. It is also a way to express intent in the form of self-documenting code. And less importantly, it also saves a few bytes of RAM.

Comment: @Lundin The reason that I write in C is .. I don't want to write in C++. Or Java. Or XML. And: if pointers to Bool are possible, a Bool cannot be represented more compact than a plain old char. And type safety is a red herring, here IMHO (see tho original question)

Comment: @Lundin Nonstandard *GCC* extensions, perhaps not (although you might be surprised to learn how many proprietary compilers do implement some subset of GCC's extensions).  Nonstandard *some compiler* extensions, almost certainly yes.  I mean, if nothing else, there's going to be inline assembly.  In the headers.  Which therefore fail to compile when the inline-assembly extension is disabled.  Yes, I have personally tripped over this one (with some iteration of VxWorks, iirc).

Comment: @zwol Most such compilers have a trick to let you use necessities even when compiling in strict mode, for example they might whine if you do `asm NOP;` but not if you do `__asm NOP;`. Similar for interrupts. Anyway, the point here is that GNU extensions as well as POSIX are completely useless for many applications. GNU extensions in particular opens up a whole bag of worms in the form of non-standard solutions to things that would otherwise be undefined behavior (just as one example: zero-length arrays).

Comment: @Lundin I get that that's your point.  _My_ point is that strict conformance modes are more trouble than they are worth, because there is just too much sloppy third-party code floating around that breaks in strict conformance modes, and that this is not just a Linux or GNU problem, it is _universal_.

Comment: I dislike that this is called nonsense. True it is dangerous, and true that gcc's default is no standard, but it was in every C standard version before that time. gcc defaulted to the old version for ages and ages because a lot of GNU code would not compile as C99 but would compile as ANSI C. Furthermore, it never became really dangerous until x64.

Comment: @zwol: @Lundin: I think that you two are discussing somewhat orthogonal issues: there's a difference between developing your own code, and just wanting someone else's sloppy code which makes assumptions about GNU-isms to compile. I'd say for new stuff, we should all use `-std=c11`, and if necessary, define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` or `_XOPEN_SOURCE` or whichever other macros as needed to include the desired stuff from headers that's not included by default - but that in no way invalidates the fact that sometimes the default makes things work that you don't have time to "fix" to work with `-std=c*`.

Comment: Note that most of the new stuff in C99 came from that 25+ year old GNU crap.

Comment: @Shahbaz Oh yeah, the GCC non-standard extensions are very nice as a playground sandbox for proposed language changes. But that doesn't necessarily mean that everyone should use them when developing new programs. You definitely shouldn't use them when you are still learning C.

Comment: Your "dangerous nonsense behavior" is better known as "backward compatibility with the then-existing C code base"; C89/C90 would have been a complete failure if it *hadn't* worked that way.

Comment: @jcast It wasn't "backwards compatibility" when C was first designed. If the language had been designed properly from the start, there wouldn't have been a need for this. All the implicit conversions going on between the lines is perhaps the biggest flaw of the language.

Comment: @Lundin, It most certainly *was* backward compatibility when C was first designed. I suggest you learn something about the history of C.

Comment: @jcast C was designed long before it became standard. Are you suggesting that non-prototype format is something that was needed for backwards-compatibility with BCPL? I will admit I know next to nothing about BCPL, kindly enlighten me of how function prototypes worked there.

Answer (score 148):

You don't have a prototype declared for `f1()` in main.c, so it is implicitly defined as `int f1()`, meaning it is a function that takes an unknown number of arguments and returns an `int`.

If `int` and `bool` are of different sizes, this will result in **[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**.  For example, on my machine, `int` is 4 bytes and `bool` is one byte.  Since the function is *defined* to return `bool`, it puts one byte on the stack when it returns.  However, since it's *implicitly declared* to return `int` from main.c, the calling function will try to read 4 bytes from the stack.

The default compilers options in gcc won't tell you that it's doing this.  But if you compile with `-Wall -Wextra`, you'll get this:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘f1’
```

To fix this, add a declaration for `f1` in main.c, before `main`:

```
bool f1(void);
```

Note that the argument list is explicitly set to `void`, which tells the compiler the function takes no arguments, as opposed to an empty parameter list which means an unknown number of arguments.  The definition `f1` in f1.c should also be changed to reflect this.

Comment: Something I used to do in my projects (when I still used GCC) was add `-Werror-implicit-function-declaration` to GCC's options, that way this one doesn't slip past anymore. An even better choice is `-Werror` to turn all warnings into errors. Forces you to fix all warnings when they show up.

Comment: You also shouldn't use empty parenthesis because doing so is an obsolescent feature. Meaning they can ban such code in the next version of the C standard.

Comment: @uliwitness Ah. Good information for those coming from C++ who only dabble in C.

Comment: The return value is usually not put into the stack, but into a register. See Owen's answer. Also, you usually never put one byte into the stack, but a multiple of the word size.

Comment: Newer versions of GCC (5.x.x) give that warning without the extra flags.

Comment: [**dbush and user253751 continued conversation**](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.theory/c/kNFbQ78YFLM)

Answer (score 39):

I think it's interesting to see where the size-mismatch mentioned in Lundin's excellent answer actually happens.

If you compile with `--save-temps`, you will get assembly files that you can look at. Here's the part where `f1()` does the `== 0` comparison and returns its value:

```
cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)
sete    %al
```

The returning part is `sete %al`. In C's x86 calling conventions, return values 4 bytes or smaller (which includes `int` and `bool`) are returned via register `%eax`. `%al` is the lowest byte of `%eax`. So, the upper 3 bytes of `%eax` are left in an uncontrolled state.

Now in `main()`:

```
call    f1
testl   %eax, %eax
je  .L2
```

This checks whether the *whole* of `%eax` is zero, because it thinks it's testing an int.

Adding an explicit function declaration changes `main()` to:

```
call    f1
testb   %al, %al
je  .L2
```

which is what we want.

Answer (score 27):

Please compile with a command such as this one:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -o main.exe main.c
```

Output:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:14:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'f1' [-Werror=impl
icit-function-declaration]
     printf( f1() == true ? "true\n" : "false\n");
     ^
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
```

With such a message, you should know what to do to correct it.

Edit: After reading a (now deleted) comment, I tried to compile your code without the flags. Well, This led me to linker errors with no compiler warnings instead of compiler errors. And those linker errors are more difficult to understand, so even if `-std-gnu99` is not necessary, please try to allways use at least `-Wall -Werror` it will save you a lot of pain in the ass.