# Implementing "!!" command in my own Linux shell

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am currently trying to build my own Linux shell from scratch as a personal project, to familiarise myself with C and Linux. I am currently on Ubuntu coding. So far the only thing my shell can do is the "echo" command and exit. I am currently trying to make my shell remember its last command by implementing `!!`.

To do this I have tried multiple options, having a linked list stack that would keep all the commands, but I ran into many problems by trying to do that.  The latest thing I tried is to simply have another string remember the last command, but I keep on getting **Segmentation Fault** error.

tldr; I am trying to implement "!!" in my shell that I am building from scratch.

Specific section I am having an issue with

```
    pre = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(cmd) + 1));
    if(!strcmp(cmd,"!!\n")){/*do nothing*/ printf("Heelo"); }
    else{
    strcpy(pre,cmd);
    }
```

**My full shell code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "shell.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <limits.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Shell is Initiaited\n");
    char *cmd;
    char *pre;
    // Stack to keep history of commands
    

    do
    {
        print_prompt1();
        cmd = read_cmd();// Read from keyboard
        
        if(!cmd)
        {
            exit(0);
            continue;
        }
        
        
        //Exit command (Up Here for priority)
        if(strcmp(cmd, "exit\n") == 0)
        {
            exit(0);
            free(cmd);
            break;
        }
        
        pre = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(cmd) + 1));
        if(!strcmp(cmd,"!!\n")){/*do nothing*/ printf("Heelo"); }
        else{
        strcpy(pre,cmd);
        }

    
        
        //All to set up only reading the first word if needed
    char *str;
    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(pre) + 1));
    strcpy(str,pre);
    char space[]=" ";
    char *cmd1= strtok(str,space);//cmd1 is the first word || command in the command/word

        
        if(!strcmp("exit", cmd1))// Exit with a spesfic Value function
        {
        char *newStr = pre;
    while (*newStr != 0 && *(newStr++) != ' ') {}// to Remove echo from the string it is echoing
    int a= atoi(newStr);
    exit(a);
            //exit(0);
            free(cmd);
            continue;
        }
    
    
            
       
        
        //If comand is empty
        if(!strcmp("", pre))
        {
            free(cmd);
            continue;
        }
        
        //If echo command is used
    if(!strcmp("echo", cmd1))
    {
    char *newStr = cmd;
    while (*newStr != 0 && *(newStr++) != ' ') {}// to Remove echo from the string it is echoing
    printf("%s",newStr);
    
      free(cmd);
      continue;
    }
        if(cmd[0] == '\0' || strcmp(cmd, "\n") == 0)
        {
            free(cmd);
            continue;
        }

        free(cmd);

    } while(1);
    printf("GoodBye \n\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


char *read_cmd(void)// Read Keyboard input
{
    char buf[1024];
    char *ptr = NULL;
    char ptrlen = 0;

    while(fgets(buf, 1024, stdin))
    {
        int buflen = strlen(buf);

        if(!ptr)
        {
            ptr = malloc(buflen+1);
        }
        else
        {
            char *ptr2 = realloc(ptr, ptrlen+buflen+1);

            if(ptr2)
            {
                ptr = ptr2;
            }
            else
            {
                free(ptr);
                ptr = NULL;
            }
        }

        if(!ptr)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to alloc buffer: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return NULL;
        }

        strcpy(ptr+ptrlen, buf);

        if(buf[buflen-1] == '\n')
        {
            if(buflen == 1 || buf[buflen-2] != '\\')
            {
                return ptr;
            }

            ptr[ptrlen+buflen-2] = '\0';
            buflen -= 2;
            print_prompt2();
        }

        ptrlen += buflen;
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger and seeing why you're getting a segfault?

Comment: `if(!strcmp(cmd,"!!\n"))` is true, then the contents of `pre` remain uninitialized.  So `strlen(pre)` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: You need to compile this with a standard C compiler then pay attention to the warnings. You haven't declared the functions you are calling anywhere, so this won't compile in standard C. It may compile in dinosaur C and gcc non-standard crap mode but then it will crash. The answer to your question: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) then fix your compiler errors from there.

Comment: Also missing function declaration bugs is very much a FAQ. Do we have a canonical dupe? There's this but I'm not sure if it makes a good canonical dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476178/this-c-function-should-always-return-false-but-it-doesn-t

Comment: Have you tried printing cmd before the statement?
Also, you have to check the allocation, if it was successful or not

Comment: Is "My full shell code" the full code btw? I assumed as much when I wrote the previous comment, but now I noticed you have a custom header shell.h which you didn't post...